# Javafx Read only HTMLEditor with copy functionality

Tags: javafx, webview, copy, readonly

Working with Java 8 HTMlEditors to show some content.
Now I want to make my content read only, in other words disable typing in the area. If I set property disabled to true this is achieved.
But the user is not able to copy some content from the field.
Is there a way that we can disable input but still can copy the content over.

Answer (score 1):

Just used a webview for this and loaded the content onto that